# R function to act differently by OS

Tags: r, linux, macos

I am trying to write a function for my package to act differently on different Operating systems,
it should basically do the same thing only in a way that each OS can handle.
Should i, or even can implement R's method system for this?
any suggestions otherwise?
The function already exists as part of the base package for windows but i have implemented it on mac osx and Linux and would like to add those function to my package.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to implement the popup window option of dir.choose in OSX and Linux, i know how to detect the OS and how to implement it for each one, just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing that except by using an 'if' statement